# JOLT transformation which involve linking by an attibutes value

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I need to transform the following input JSON into the format outlined here below using JOLT. The linkage is to be done by the deps.name of first array element with spec.name of the second array element. I am clueless about the linking. Thanks for your help.

Input json

```json
[
  {
    "key": "Primary",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "35f8d9fac891"
    },
    "deps": [
      {
        "name": "e6ae6d29edf8"
      }
    ],
    "spec": {
      "vattr1": "vval1",
      "vattr2": "vval2"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Secondary",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "hp74z"
    },
    "spec": {
      "name": "e6ae6d29edf8",
      "nattr1": "nval1",
      "nattr2": "nval2",
      "deps": {
        "Name": "5505da219463"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output format expected

```
{
  "key": "Primary",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "35f8d9fac891"
  },
  "deps": [
    {
      "name": {
        "key": "Secondary",
        "metadata": {
          "name": "hp74z"
        },
        "spec": {
          "name": "e6ae6d29edf8",
          "nattr1": "nval1",
          "nattr2": "nval2",
          "deps": {
            "Name": "5505da219463"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "spec": {
    "vattr1": "vval1",
    "vattr2": "vval2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this spec in order to see whether those two objects of the array to be accumulated within a new array with key a common name(**"e6ae6d29edf8"**) such as

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "@(0)": "@(1,spec.name)",
      "@": "@(1,deps[&].name)"
    }
  }
}
```

the test would fail, if those names(one from **spec.name** and the other from **deps[].name**) don't match(*just try it!*)

then use

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": "common"
    }
  }
}
```

in order to get rid of that confusing key name(**"e6ae6d29edf8"**) by converting it to **"common"**. Now, we get array of two objects, and need to replace the value of **"deps"** array with the second object. **modify** transformation spec is designed to do such manipulations. Then, pick only the **"common"** object by using a **shift** transformation spec.

Thus, full spec will be :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0)": "@(1,spec.name)",
        "@": "@(1,deps[&].name)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "common"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))",
      "SecondaryObject": "=lastElement(@(1,common))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "deps": {
          "*": "=(@(3,SecondaryObject))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit**(*considering the case that there exists multiple objects to be embedded as commented*) :

Then you can determine an attribute `"name_val"` in the first spec to be used as the common identifier value to be used within the upcoming specs such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0)": "@(1,spec.name)",
        "@": "@(1,deps[&].name)",
        "@(0,deps[&].name)": "name_val"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,name_val)": {
            "@1": "common[&2]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "0": "c1",
        "*": "c2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c1": {
        "deps": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=(@(4,c2))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c1": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Barbaros for your response. Instead of using lastElement(@(1,common))", is there a way we can pick it using the spec.name match? Because, there may be a possibility, there is an additional json element be added at the end.. In that case, the lastElement would no longer be the one I am looking for.

Comment: You're right @guru , a generic case would be better. I'm able to build it just now. Best wishes.